# Jquery select un select checkbox on clicking title

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, checkbox

I have written code to select unselect based on checkbox click and unclick. How can I select and unselect based on clicking title of that checkbox next to it? I will have ids dynamically.

[Fiddle code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/T5M5h/)

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^='columnCheckbox_']", function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('unchkd')) {
            $(this).removeClass('unchkd').addClass('chkd');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('chkd').addClass('unchkd');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function (e) {
    $(this).find('div[id^=columnCheckbox_]').toggleClass('unchkd chkd')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FACAT/)

- [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

---

I would recommend addition an additional class to the div to style it like

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="chkd checkbox" id="columnCheckbox_1" value="chkbox_Title"></div>
        <div class="2" style="padding-left: 20px;" value="colName_Title">Title</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="chkd checkbox" id="columnCheckbox_2" value="chkbox_Title"></div>
        <div class="2" style="padding-left: 20px;" value="colName_Title">desc</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

then

```
.chkd {
    background-color: #29abe1;
}
.unchkd {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.checkbox {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    float: left;
}
```

and

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function (e) {
    $(this).find('.checkbox').toggleClass('unchkd chkd')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4WmDK/)